# Estimating coefficients for ordered, grouped independent variables against binomial distribution

Tags: regression, ordinal-data

I have about 170 samples. Each sample has a dependent variable of between 0 and 1, representing the incidence of an unseen characteristic. The samples are of different sizes. For each sample, the population is distributed across 65 different categories.

I am trying to find a model that can predict the incidence, given the distribution over the different categories.

I have tried running a glm model of the incidence against the counts against each category. However I'm not certain that's the right approach.

In any event, I'm throwing away information. The categories are interrelated. First, they are in a grouping hierarchy; there are 11 groups of categories. So the first 4 are pretty similar, as are the second 5, and so on. (For anyone from the UK, who is aware of these, they are in fact Mosaic codes, produced by experian).

Secondly, they are roughly ordered. Not only are the first 4 pretty similar to each other, but they are more similar to the next 5, than they are to the last 5.

How should I reflect those relationships?

Comment: This liners on unanswered because there is too little information: "incidence of an unseen characteristic"? Do you have the numerator and denominator separately? Please clarify the information!